# How do you reference a Wix Project Output from an Installer Vdproj project?

Tags: wix, installation, setup-project, vdproj

I have a .vdproj setup project, unfortunately, and it references some Wix projects.
Unfortunately the reference can only really be a File (full path) as the Project Output reference only permits .dll and .exe, the Wix ouput is .msi.

Comment: If you're already using WiX, what possible reason can there be to not replace the `.vdproj` with another WiX project? (Usually, if someone's trying to do something moderately complex with a `.vdproj` the recommendation would be "switch to WiX" with a warning that it has quite a learning curve to it - but that would seem to not be an issue here)

Comment: Get away from .VDproj, I believe even Microsoft ditched it from VS2013.

Comment: Ditch it, that would be wonderful. It's massive, a mini project to convert it. I know only too well the problems with .vdproj but none of the comments answer my question.

Comment: If I understand, you don't need to use the VS setup projects "Project Output" thing. Just add the WiX MSI path as a file to whereever you want to install it to. You're trying to copy a WiX generated MSI file to the system during the install of your VS-generated MSI? 
I

Comment: thanks, thats what we have, points to the msi, its the dependencies that are the issue. our build scripts must have the sequence right and the correct configuration must be build first in order for the setup to know which file to point to i.e. if we point to an msi in the Release output directory then we must be sure that we always build in Release first in order for the file to exist.